# Can we use the localhost as a server name while Power BI gateway connection?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am not able to establish a connection with Power BI gateway with the server name as "localhost". Please guide me. Can we use the localhost as a server name while Power BI gateway connection? or we need to use an IP address for the SQL server name as a credential.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should [be possible](https://sqlserverbi.blog/2018/09/14/how-to-configure-the-power-bi-gateway-to-use-dataset-connection-parameters/).

Note that you'll need to [use database credentials](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32004.power-bi-tips-for-working-with-mysql.aspx), not Windows credentials.